# How to check if a component has a signal?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

There is a reliable way to check from QML/JavaScript if a component has a signal?

At the moment I found that this code work as intended:

```
if (myCustomComponent.myCustomSignal)
    myCustomComponent.myCustomSignal();
```

Where `myCustomComponent` is even as simple as this:

```
 Item {
    id: root

    signal myCustomSignal()
 }
```

The signal is executed only if `myCustomComponent` has it but I'm not sure if is the correct way.

Answer (score -2):

No, more reliable way should be to check if component has a signal could be:

```
if (typeof root.myCustomSignal !== 'undefined' && typeof root.myCustomSignal === 'function') { ... }
```

or

```
if (typeof root.myCustomSignal === 'function') { ... }
```

Using boolean is not realiable. Change your sample target item to:

```
Item {
    id: root

    property bool myCustomSignal: true
}
```

In this case your condition will be true and you will try invoke a property what will lead to crash.
This approach is less error prone and it ensure that signal exists and is invokable/function.

Comment: How is this better than a `Boolean()` check? If is `undefined` it will return `false`.

Comment: Err, you need to update your information about how javascript handle undefined values, type comparison add nothing in this case, checking against string values is not safer than a boolean value

Comment: Just try to obtain something other than a boolean from `if (anything_you_want_that_is_undefined)`, you will see and understand why there is no need to do a `typeof` check in this case, regardless of the result you will always get `false` for `undefined`.